# "Application not found" Error while trying to login to JetBrains account from IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

When I click on Login, it shows this error

[image]

Comment: Add the relevant code as text in the question, not as image. It's easier, faster and is displayable by anyone. And put a relevant title

Comment: @jhamon I fixed the question. There's no code. There's a problem with IntelliJ Idea itself.

Comment: Do other links in that dialog work?

Answer (score 1):

This is Windows-specific issue. It happens if the default browser is not set or the html file association and/or http protocol associations are not correctly set. The same error may occur when double-clicking an Internet Shortcut (.URL) file in the system.

To resolve the problem, use Default Programs to reset the default Web browser preference.